# Buildout adding eggs to existing recipe

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid, buildout

**Edit2:** added entire stderr

**Edit1:** deleted my supposed answer. Updated description of problem and added full `buildout.cfg` text

**Edit0:** fixed links

I am trying to port a Pyramid project I have to Google App Engine. I am attempting to leverage Tobias Rodaebel's (thanks!) [buildout recipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rod.recipe.appengine) that aids in this. I used the pyramid_appengine scaffold, essentially following the procedure described [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae_buildout.html).

Things went relatively smoothly until I tried to add additional eggs to the buildout. I attempt to add the `pymongo` package to the `./buildout.cfg` file,

```
[buildout]
include-site-packages=false
find-links=http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/
extends = versions.cfg
versions = versions
update-versions-file = versions.cfg
show-picked-versions = true
develop=src/bkk
parts=bkk
    tests
    service-bkk
ae-sdk-version=1.9.18
ae-runtime=2.7
ae-sdk-location = ${buildout:parts-directory}/google_appengine
ae-extra-paths =
            ${buildout:bin-directory}
        ${buildout:directory}/parts/bkk
        ${buildout:directory}/parts/google_appengine
            ${buildout:directory}/parts/google_appengine/lib/antlr3
            ${buildout:directory}/parts/google_appengine/lib/django
            ${buildout:directory}/parts/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib
            ${buildout:directory}/parts/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib
unzip=true
supervisor-port = 9999
supervisor-conf-dir = ${buildout:directory}/conf
supervisor-log-dir = ${buildout:directory}/var/log
service-conf-templates = ${buildout:directory}/conf.tmpl
project-name=bkk

[bkk]
recipe=rod.recipe.appengine
packages=
    pyramid
    pymongo
    pyramid_jinja2
    repoze.lru
    zope.interface
    zope.deprecation
    venusian
    translationstring
    jinja2
    webob
src=src/bkk
server-script=devappserver
zip-packages=false
use_setuptools_pkg_resources=true
url=https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_${buildout:ae-sdk-version}.zip

[bootstrap]
recipe=zc.recipe.egg
eggs=pastescript
extra-paths=${buildout:ae-extra-paths}

[tests]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    WebTest
    WebOb
    pytest
    pytest-cov
interpreter = python
extra-paths=${buildout:ae-extra-paths}


[supervisor]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg

[mk-supervisor-log-dir]
recipe = collective.recipe.cmd:py
on_install = true
cmds =
    >>> if not os.path.isdir('${buildout:supervisor-log-dir}'):os.makedirs('${buildout:supervisor-log-dir}')

[service-supervisor]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:service-conf-templates}/supervisord.conf_tmpl
output = ${buildout:directory}/etc/supervisord.conf
depends = ${mk-supervisor-log-dir:recipe} ${supervisor:recipe}

[service-bkk]
recipe = collective.recipe.template
input = ${buildout:service-conf-templates}/service-${buildout:project-name}.conf_tmpl
output = ${buildout:supervisor-conf-dir}/service-${buildout:project-name}.conf
port=8000
admin_port=8010
api_port=8020
depends = ${service-supervisor:recipe}
```

and also unzip the corresponding egg into the `./eggs` directory. I end up getting the following error:

```
Develop: '/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/src/bkk'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'paster_plugins'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: no files found matching '*.ini'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.pt' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.mak' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.mako' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.js' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'bkk'
warning: no files found matching '*.xml' under directory 'bkk'
Uninstalling bkk.
Unused options for buildout: 'ae-runtime' 'include-site-packages' 'unzip'.
Installing bkk.
rod.recipe.appengine: Google App Engine distribution already downloaded.
While:
  Installing bkk.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/eggs/zc.buildout-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1946, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/eggs/zc.buildout-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 626, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/eggs/zc.buildout-2.3.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1370, in _call
    return f()
  File "/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/eggs/rod.recipe.appengine-2.0.6-py2.7.egg/rod/recipe/appengine/__init__.py", line 380, in install
    self.copy_packages(ws, temp_dir)
  File "/Users/npk1/Dev/bkk/bkk_gae/bkk/eggs/rod.recipe.appengine-2.0.6-py2.7.egg/rod/recipe/appengine/__init__.py", line 290, in copy_packages
    raise KeyError, '%s: package not found.' % p
KeyError: 'pyramid_jinja2: package not found.'
```

Walking through the code it seems that the `zc.recipe` is assembling its own list of dependencies and checking them against my projects and `pymongo` does not show up, though perhaps I am wrong.

Does anyone know the process when adding new packages to an existing recipe? Is that the wrong way to think about it? I will continue to try to digest buildout's documentation, as I am new to the utility.

Thanks

Comment: Note that both links in your question lead to the page for some old version of `zc.recipe.egg` which is not quite relevant to the question. I also suspect that `packages=` is meant to be `eggs=` and `zc.recipe` is actually `zc.recipe.egg`. All this makes quite difficult to decipher what's going on :) Can you show us your complete buildout.cfg and tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Sergey my apologies! Not sure how that happened. Fixed the links. Actually, `packages` is indeed the label.

Answer (score 0):

Pyramid has a [cookbook of recipes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/).

These two recipes describe how to deploy Pyramid on GAE.  Both provide guidance using a different method than the path you started down.

[Pyramid on Google’s App Engine (using buildout)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae_buildout.html)

[Pyramid on Google’s App Engine (using appengine-monkey)](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/deployment/gae.html)

Comment: I actually meant to include the buildout link but somehow failed. Fixed this in an edit.